# Set latitude and longitude in Exif, but Gallery App doesn't recognize the updated Exif GPS location?

Tags: android, image, gps, jpeg, exif

I follow the tutorial post from the blog http://android-coding.blogspot.com/2011/10/set-latitude-and-longitude-in-exif.html, but I have the same problem mentioned by the blogger, the new location recognized by Gallery App.

The updated location can be read using exifInterface.getLatLong(LatLong), so I suppose it have be write correctly. Anybody can advise?

Answer (score 0):

Actually code is working.
You need to check it in another device by sending via bluetooth. Our device maintains lat and long of image in its own database where as TAG_GPS_LATITUDE is saved with image. And gallery displays lat and long from database.